# ICMP listener problems

Tags: c#, sockets

It’s always pleasing when a piece of software works the way you want to, but as long as I don’t understand precisely why (or how) it works I consider that a big problem. I made an ICMP listener to compensate for a flaw in the ’UdpClient’ class, that will not return appropriate ICMP messages resulting from requests made when unexpectedly the remote host becomes unavailable. (ICMP Type 3, any Code). Instead of replying with an ICMP code, it simply throws an error: (WSACONNRESET) and ‘Cannot access a disposed object’.

The code as I have it running now uses ManualResetEvents as signaling, which is acceptable. The resulting data has been carefully checked, even at time-slot and sequence number level, and all is well. I just don’t understand why a new ‘StateObject’ is required for every iteration of the loop. 
There is no reason that I am aware of that states that the current buffer cannot be re-used. Nevertheless, if I don’t use a new one every iteration, the buffer returned is invalid (no errors though); the buffer then refers to a packet from my host to an external destination instead of a buffer from a remote host. Therefore, I see my system’s reply to an echo (Type 0) request, instead of the actual echo request (Type 8) received (as seen in Wireshark). As soon as I change the loop to use a new ‘StateObject’, all is well again. The examples of Microsoft did not include a disposable ‘StateObject’, so I made a new class that inherits from IDisposable for that purpose.

Furthermore, when switching from ManualResetEvent signaling to ‘AsyncWaitHandle’ signaling, the process only works when using a recursive call to the callback delegate. If I don’t, the ’IASyncResult’ ‘IsCompleted’ is not always set (even though all buffers are the same 60 bytes), so it will wait indefinitely on the handle.

A long story (and a lot of code) but I hope someone will be able to shed some light on these issues.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using log4net;

namespace ICMPTest
{
    public class ICMPCheck
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent gotMessage;
        private static IPAddress ipAddress;
        private static IntPtr stateHandle; // Dont know what it is for, or what to do with it
        private static Disposables.StateObject so = null;
        private static Socket icmpClient;
        private static EndPoint remoteRawEndPoint = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        public static Queue<byte[]> m_icmpQueue = new Queue<byte[]>();
        public static object m_syncLock = new object();
        private static IPEndPoint NIC = null;
        private static int Queued = 0;
        private static int DeQueued = 0;
        private static int CallCount = 0;
        public static IAsyncResult iar;

        public static void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                using (icmpClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp))
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                    IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                    IPAddress[] address = hostInfo.AddressList;
                    ipAddress = address[0];
                    NIC = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0);
                    icmpClient.Bind(NIC); // Bind to localhost, port any
                    byte[] inBytes = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                    byte[] outBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                    icmpClient.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, inBytes, outBytes); //only outgoing packets
                    icmpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        //gotMessage = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        using (so = new Disposables.StateObject(stateHandle))
                        {

                            so.workSocket = icmpClient;

                            iar = icmpClient.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, Disposables.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, ref remoteRawEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromCallback), so); //blocking

                            iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); //gotMessage.WaitOne(); //iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); // seems to be unreliable

                            for (int i = DeQueued; i < Queued; i++)
                            {
                                //DequeueParse.DequeueAndParse(ref so);
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref DeQueued);
                                ICMPProgram.logger.Debug("ICMPCheck-0: Signal + Message received: " + remoteRawEndPoint.ToString() + " Queue: " + m_icmpQueue.Count.ToString() + " " + Queued.ToString() + " " + DeQueued.ToString());
                            }
                        } // using StateObject
                        //gotMessage.Dispose();
                    }// while
                }//using Socket
            } // try
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                ICMPProgram.logger.Error("ICMPCheck: Exception Mainblock. " + excp.Message);
            }
            return;
        }

        private static void ReceiveFromCallback(IAsyncResult iar) 
        { 
            Interlocked.Increment(ref CallCount);
            try
            {
                if (ICMPProgram.stopRequest) return;
                Disposables.StateObject state = (Disposables.StateObject)iar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = ((Disposables.StateObject)iar.AsyncState).workSocket;
                EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                int bytesRead = client.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref tempRemoteEP);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    if (!(((IPEndPoint)tempRemoteEP).Address).Equals(NIC.Address)) // ignore messages from local host
                    {
                        byte[] _icmpData = new byte[bytesRead];
                        byte[] icmpType = new byte[1];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(state.buffer, 20, icmpType, 0, 1);

                        //if (((int)icmpType[0] == 3)) // only type 3
                        if (true) // all tyoes for now
                        {
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(state.buffer, 0, _icmpData, 0, bytesRead); 
                            lock (m_syncLock)
                            {
                                m_icmpQueue.Enqueue(_icmpData);
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref Queued);
                            }
                        }
                        // the next callback is required when using AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne signaling, not required (but useful for high volume) for ManualResetEvents
                        client.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, Disposables.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, ref tempRemoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromCallback), state); // suitable for high volume
                        remoteRawEndPoint = tempRemoteEP;
                        //ICMPProgram.logger.Debug("ICMPCheck: Bytes: " + bytesRead.ToString() + ", Type: " + icmpType[0].ToString() + " " + tempRemoteEP.ToString() + " " + m_icmpQueue.Count.ToString() + " " + Queued.ToString() + " " + CallCount.ToString() + " " + iar.IsCompleted.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ICMPProgram.logger.Debug("ICMPCheck: bytesRead = 0 ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                ICMPProgram.logger.Debug("ICMPCheck:ReceiveFromCallback main " + excp.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //gotMessage.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iar = icmpClient.BeginReceiveFrom(...);
iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

There is no point in using BeingReceiveFrom() and then wait for the asynchronous operation to complete.  Just use ReceiveFrom().  Now you don't need that 'StateObject' anymore either to let the callback know what request the response belongs to.

Comment: Just done that; works like a charm. (and with a lot less code!) Thanks.