# How to receive ICMP response "Port unreachable" to UDP message in C#

Tags: c#, udp, icmp

I'm trying to receive ICMP response "Port unreachable" to UDP message in `C#` this is what I'm trying to do:

```cs
IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.211.133"), 0);
var udpClient = new UdpClient("192.168.211.133", 20);
Byte[] messagebyte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hi".ToCharArray());
int s = udpClient.Send(messagebyte, messagebyte.Length);
Byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new Byte[256];
ReceiveBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndpoint);
```

but the program is stuck on

```
ReceiveBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndpoint);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of UDP is that there may not BE a response. After a certain amount of time has passed, you need to assume that the destination is unreadable.

Take a look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281441/can-i-set-the-timeout-for-udpclient-in-c).

Comment: This is not entirely true, if port is unrechable, icmp packet is sent from destination with "unrechable port" message.  I know for a fact that this udp port is unrechable. I checked it with wire shark and there is a icmp packet sent from destination to me, but for some reason I can't catch it.

Comment: But thanks for the link, it solved me a "How to wait for response" question i was lookig answer for :)

Comment: maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/f8d9b559-fa29-4596-b6db-35f455fd88f8/) will help?

Comment: Here's another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097165/icmp-listener-problems).

Comment: Thanks,I tried that and i still didn't catch that packet. I think it's a sync issue. Packet is gone when i'm trying to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

if you catch a exception and SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset, that means you receive "Port unreachable".

Or, you can set a socket use protocol Icmp, like this:

`Socket icmp = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);`

Answer (score 0):

The address seems to be the issue i tried it and if you change it for 127.0.0.1 you do receive the icmp message